# UWP : Need to disable on-screen-keyboard on textbox click

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, xamarin.uwp, windows-community-toolkit, uwp-navigation

UWP : Need to disable on-screen-keyboard on textbox click

Because I need to Invoke third Party on-screen-keyboard.

Tried Below Code....But I was not able to disable on-screen-keyboard.

```
PreventKeyboardDisplayOnProgrammaticFocus="True"
```

Both are getting Invoked Microsoft on-screen-keyboard and Third Party Keyboard.

Its not Working, But I tried `"ishittestvisible=false"` Its Working, But All Mouse Events are Blocked.

**Any of the Solution is Fine..1. either disable on-screen-keyboard or 2.after making `ishittestvisible=false` Mouse Events Should Work.**

Comment: You can set [InputPaneDisplayPolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.text.core.coretexteditcontext.inputpanedisplaypolicy#Windows_UI_Text_Core_CoreTextEditContext_InputPaneDisplayPolicy) to Manual.

Comment: Can you please provide the code to implement this on textbox in UWP...You can take sample uwp Textbox and Disable on-screen-keyboard on click...

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke. That's for custom text boxes you write yourself, not for modifying existing ones. You can listen for InputPane.Showing and immediately hide it. In the TouchKeyboard sample, add `sender.TryHide();` at [line 50](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/08d7459c552fe1065d3fe195b3fe2a5d7ec3b567/Samples/TouchKeyboard/cs/Scenario2_ShowHideEvents.xaml.cs#L50).

Answer (score 0):

The code below works for me in a WinUI 3 (Windows App SDK) application. It should work for UWP as well. It completely prevents the keyboard from showing, without blinking/flickering.

```
public sealed partial class CustomTextBox
{

    private void CustomTextBox_OnGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CoreInputView.GetForCurrentView().PrimaryViewShowing += BlockOnScreenKeyboard;
    }

    private void CustomTextBox_OnLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CoreInputView.GetForCurrentView().PrimaryViewShowing -= BlockOnScreenKeyboard;
    }

    private static void BlockOnScreenKeyboard(CoreInputView sender, CoreInputViewShowingEventArgs args)
    {
        args.TryCancel(); 
        sender.TryHide();
    }

    ...
}
```

`args.TryCancel()` does the job alone but when the app loses focus, the keyboard appears, so `sender.TryHide()` is needed to eliminate this bad-looking behavior.